# Share table variable between Stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: stored-procedures

Is it possible to store the results of a call to exec sp_executesql in a 'table parameter'.  The parameter value is used in another SQL Stored procedure (SQL 2000/2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best you can do is insert the values into a temp table (using an INSERT EXEC pattern) and then use that temp table in the second proc down the chain ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to store the results of some process in a table variable, I would suggest making it a table-value function instead of a sproc. That way you can then use the end-result of the first function in whatever other processing you are doing

```
Select * from MyTableValueFunction()
```